# How to simplify huge if-statement in .filter body?

Tags: java, if-statement, filter, java-8, java-stream

Is there a better meaning more readable way to express this?

```
    List<LocationVO> listLocation = listLocationAll.stream().filter(l -> {
        boolean ok = true;
        if ( filter.getClient_id() != null && filter.getClient_id().longValue() !=  l.getParent_client_id() ) {
            ok = false;
        }
        if ( filter.getLocation_id() != null && filter.getLocation_id().longValue() !=  l.getLocation_id() ) {
            ok = false;
        }
        if (filter.getLocation_type() != null && (filter.getLocation_type().equals(l.getLocation_type()) == false) ) {
            ok = false;
        }
        return ok;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

LocationVO cotains:

```
public class LocationVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long location_id;
    private long parent_client_id;
    private String name;
    private String location_type;
    ...
}
```

filter is of type LocationFilter and contains:

```
public class LocationFilter implements Serializable {

    private Long client_id;
    private Long location_id;
    private String location_type;
}
```

First if statement:
If a filter was set for the client id -> do not contain any LocationVO whose associated client does not have this id

Second if statement:
If a filter was set for location -> remove/filter all LocationVO that do not have this id

Third if statement:
Filter all VOs that do not have the location_type of the filter.

(( I think, none are obsolete (( as mentioned in the comments)) ))

Comment: You can use just filters without the "ok" stuff... each condition as a different predicate...

Comment: `filter.getClient_id().longValue()`.. what is filter here?

Comment: @nullpointer my best guess is that it should be `l` instead ...

Comment: @JorgeCampos nope, notice `l.getParent_client_id()` later in the `if` condition.

Comment: @nullpointer  oooh, you are right!! o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build up the `Predicate<LocationVO` in stages:

```
    Predicate<LocationVO> p = l -> true;
    if (filter.getClient_id() != null) {
        p = p.and(l -> filter.getClient_id().longValue() !=  l.getParent_client_id());
    }
    if (filter.getLocation_id() != null) {
        p = p.and(l -> l.getLocation_id().longValue() == filter.getLocation_id());
    }
    if (filter.getLocation_type() != null) {
        p = p.and(l -> filter.getLocation_type().equals(l.getLocation_type()));
    }
```

and then use the built predicate to filter the stream:

```
    List<LocationVO> listLocation = listLocationAll.stream()
            .filter(p)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now, if you move the predicate building into the `filter`s class, it looks even nicer:

```
    // within the class of "filter"
    Predicate<LocationVO> createLocationVOPredicate() {
        Predicate<LocationVO> p = l -> true;
        if (getClient_id() != null) {
            p = p.and(l -> getClient_id().longValue() ==  l.getParent_client_id());
        }
        if (getLocation_id() != null) {
            p = p.and(l -> l.getLocation_id().longValue() == getLocation_id());
        }
        if (getLocation_type() != null) {
            p = p.and(l -> getLocation_type().equals(l.getLocation_type()));
        }
        return p;
    }
```

and the usage:

```
    listLocation = listLocationAll.stream()
            .filter(filter.createLocationVOPredicate())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the rest of the logic would have a sequential check of each attribute to add to the filtering condition. You can move such logic to `equals`(along with `hashCode`) implementation within the object itself and then again use a simpler stream pipeline as :

```
List<LocationVO> filterList(List<LocationVO> input, LocationVO elem) {
    return input.stream()
        .filter(o -> elem.equals(o))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Why are the first two conditions not effective? For example the first condition: if `filter.getClient_id()` is not null and `filter.getClient_id().longValue() !=  l.getParent_client_id()` then `ok` will be set to false and remain false no matter what the remaining conditions are, so the function result will be false

Comment: @ThomasKläger but then that state of `ok` would not be used further in the code in question...just try to iterate through that entire `filter` block.

Comment: That state of `ok` is the return value of the function (there is no code after that that might make `ok` true again). It doesn't need be used otherwise in the remainder of the code.